# How do save all request data to database

Tags: php, laravel

how can save all to Database?

```
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'street' => 'required',
        'street_addition' => 'nullable',
        'postal_code' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'vat_id' => 'nullable'
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $billingDetail = $user->billingDetails()->save(new UserBillingDetail([
        $request->all()
    ]));
```

the `$request->all()` dont work. idk why. it comes

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a
> default value" and email and and and...

Comment: try    $billingDetail = $user->billingDetails()->save(new UserBillingDetail(
        $request->all()));

Comment: A bit if a long way of saying "try taking the square brackets out of UserBillingDetail" @JohnLobo?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What does `$request->all()` return?

Answer (score 1):

The error message already give you the answear. you pass data and some fields are empty.
first of all: make sure that this fields not empty. After then check if the fields are declare as fillable in your model. `protected $fillable = [...]`

Answer (score 1):

The SQL error you are experiencing is because your columns doesn't allow `NULL` values and it produces this error, when you try and put in a row with empty values.

The reason why your values are empty, is because you're wrapping your `UserBillingDetail` construct parameter with an `[]`:

```
$billingDetail = $user->billingDetails()->save(new UserBillingDetail([
    $request->all()
]));
```

This will effectively send an array with a single key (`0`) containing the value of your `request->all()`. Hence, the `name`, `email`, etc., fields doesn't exist in the top level array (which is what you want).

You should remove the extra brackets, making your code look like this:

```
$billingDetail = $user->billingDetails()->save(new UserBillingDetail(
    $request->all()
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using $request->except('_token') in place of $request->all() as the request also have _token key in it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

error message already give you the answer. you pass data and some fields are empty. or make the field nullable.